# <Vulkan> Use rendered vkImage as Texture

Tags: vulkan

I want to use a vkImage rendered at a previous render pass as Texture to do the composite operation in a fragment shader. From [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/blob/master/samples/performance/pipeline_barriers/pipeline_barriers.cpp) I learned vkCmdPipelineBarrier is used to wait for GPU finish a rendering operation and I write this code. It works well on Snapdragon devices. But not on Mali-G52. The Write-after-write error is partly happed. Is this code not enough? Any suggestions?

```cpp
vkCmdEndRenderPass(cb);
vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cb, &renderPassBeginInfo, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
VkViewport viewport = vks::initializers::viewport((float)offscreenPass.width, (float)offscreenPass.height, 0.0f, 1.0f);
vkCmdSetViewport(cb, 0, 1, &viewport);
VkRect2D scissor = vks::initializers::rect2D(offscreenPass.width, offscreenPass.height, 0, 0);
vkCmdSetScissor(cb, 0, 1, &scissor);
 // https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/blob/master/samples/performance/pipeline_barriers/pipeline_barriers.cpp
VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarrier = vks::initializers::imageMemoryBarrier();
imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.image = offscreenPass.color[drawframe].image;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
cb,
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &imageMemoryBarrier);
imageMemoryBarrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
imageMemoryBarrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_DEPTH_STENCIL_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
imageMemoryBarrier.image = offscreenPass.depth.image;
imageMemoryBarrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
imageMemoryBarrier.dstAccessMask = 0;
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(
cb,
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT,
VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT,
0, 0, nullptr, 0, nullptr, 1, &imageMemoryBarrier);
```

I have tried every pattern written [here](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Samples/blob/master/samples/performance/pipeline_barriers/pipeline_barriers.cpp).

Comment: What do your validation layers tell you?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to synchronize render passes then your pipeline barrier must be outside of the render pass in the command stream. I.e. it must be after the `vkCmdEndRenderPass()` of the first pass, and before the `vkCmdBeginRenderPass()` of the second pass. Pipeline barriers issued inside a render pass, as you are currently doing, are used for synchronization only within the current subpass.

Also, try to avoid:

```
srcStage=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT
dstStage=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT
```

... for pipeline barriers when you only consume the output of the first pass as a fragment shader input in the second. This is overly conservative and needlessly serializes execution of the geometry processing too. In this case, you should use:

```
srcStage=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT
dstStage=VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT
```

... which allows the non-dependent vertex shading and binning for the second pass to run in parallel to the first pass.

Comment: "*your pipeline barrier must be outside of the render pass in the command stream*" Is there a reason why you can't just use external subass dependencies instead of a barrier?

Comment: That should work too.

Answer (score 0):

Self solved.

The difference in the precision of sampler2D between Adreno and Mali causes this issue. I can read correct data using "precision highp sampler2D".